# pandas merge columns to a single time series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with 3 boolean columns:

```
    A     B     C
0   True  False False
1   False True  False
2   True  Nan   False
3   False False True
...
```

Only one column is true at each time, but there can be Nan.

I would like to get a list of column names where the name is chosen based on the boolean. So for the example above:

```
['A', 'B', 'A', 'C']
```

it's a simple matrix operation, not sure how to map it to pandas...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `mul` operator between the dataframe and the dataframe columns. That results in `True` cells containing the column name and `False` cells empty. Eventually you can just sum the row data:

```
df.mul(df.columns).sum(axis=1)
Out[44]: 
0    A
1    B
2    A
3    C
```

Answer (score 0):

You can index columns names, i.e. `df.columns`, with proper indexes:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df.columns[(df * np.arange(df.values.shape[1])).sum(axis=1)]
Index([u'A', u'B', u'A', u'C'], dtype=object)
```

*Explanation*.

Expression

```
>>> df * np.arange(df.values.shape[1])
   A  B  C
0  0  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  0
3  0  0  2
```

calculates for each column a proper index, then matrix is summed row-wize with

```
>>> (df * np.arange(df.values.shape[1])).sum(axis=1)
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    2
dtype: int32
```